# Inserting Index along with column values from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

If i have two data frames df1 and df2:

df1

```
    yr
24  1984
30  1985
```

df2

```
    d   m   yr
16  12   4  2012
17  13  10  1976
18  24   4    98
```

I would like to have a dataframe that gives an output as below, could you help with the function that could help me achieve this

```
    d   m   yr
16  12   4  2012
17  13  10  1976
18  24   4    98
24  NaN NaN 1984
30  NaN NaN 1985
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) two dataframes:

```
res = pd.concat([df2, df1], sort=False)

print(res)

       d     m    yr
16  12.0   4.0  2012
17  13.0  10.0  1976
18  24.0   4.0    98
24   NaN   NaN  1984
30   NaN   NaN  1985
```

Comment: What if there are is index number 19,20,25,31 also in df1. How do I go about it then?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is in that situation. This method will still work, have you tried it?

Comment: Oh... there were some more operations that were needed to be performed... once I did that .. it worked.... thanks